# Forbidden ... denying access to be safe

Tags: permissions, .htaccess, lamp, raspbian, forbidden

Total n00b here.

I'm running a LAMP stack using Raspbian OS on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B.

I tried googling around, but I couldn't find a thread that matched my issue.

My jenga tower seemed pretty stable. However, in the last week, I've started receiving the following error when attempting to load any pages from my server.

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access [directory] on this server. Server
> unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

If I reboot the server, the problem goes away, and I can access my pages, but the issue returns again after a short while.

I figure some kind of process is tweaking with the permissions, but I don't what it is.

The last thing I recall doing before this occurred was installing unattended upgrades. I removed that, but it didn't resolve the problem.

As a n00b, I don't know where to start, or what to look for. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to mention, as part of my setup, I was booting from usb, rather than the built in sd.

For my backup, I had an additional drive plugged into the second usb. However, I hadn't actually set up the backup yet, so the second usb drive was empty.

It turns out, that at some point, the OS would flip over and start attempting to read from the backup, instead of the boot drive. Not sure why this was happening but, unplugging the backup drive stopped the errors from occurring.

This is great, but creates a new problem for me. No backup. If/when I work out a solution for that, I'll be sure to post it here.

Comment: Don't bother. Running stuff on raspberry pis [is off topic here](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5586/are-raspberrypis-ever-on-topic-for-serverfault).